# Value in array in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a more straightforward way to do the "value-in-array" pattern than the following in BigQuery? I find it quite difficult to do (especially if items are nested) and I always have to look up what to do (with the whole cross-join-unnest) every time I end up doing it. What I currently have is:

```
with arr_tbl as (
  select 1 as id, ["pear", "mango"] as fruits union all
  select 2 as id, ["pear", "apricot"]
)
select id, fruits from arr_tbl, unnest(fruits) as fruit where fruit="mango"
```

There couldn't be something simpler such as a function like the following would there?

```
value_in_array(arr, val)
```

I'm so used to do something like the following in languages:

```
>>> 1 in [1,2,3]
True
```

Hopefully there is some way to treat it like a normal expression list:

```
WHERE 1 in (1,2,3)
```

Or, compare with:

```
select list_contains([1,2,3],1);
┌────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ list_contains(main.list_value(1, 2, 3), 1) │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│                                       true │
```

Comment: Have you seen this ? [scanning arrays] (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#scanning_arrays).  In your case, `WHERE "mango" IN UNNEST(fruits)` and `1 IN UNNEST([1, 2, 3])` will work.

Comment: @Jaytiger awesome -- is there an equivalent for a json array? For example: `select 1 in unnest(json_extract_array(json '[1,2,3]'))` ?

Comment: @Jaytiger one option is to string-encode the value to check in a json value array (string[]) -- `select '1' in unnest(json_value_array(json '[1,2,3]'))` works.

Comment: Yes, most json functrions return a value as string type, it should be compared as string like your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@David542, As you have mentioned in the comment, the below query gives output as per your requirement.

```
with arr_tbl as (
  select 1 as id, ["pear", "mango"] as fruits union all
  select 2 as id, ["pear", "apricot"]
)
select '1' in unnest(json_value_array(json '[1,2,3]'))
```

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.